# Laravel 5.1 route:list breaks on controller AJAX check

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5, routes, abort

When I try to get route list in command line with `php artisan route:list` i get this error:
[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException]

Seems like my AjaxController's constructor is throwing an exception for every ajax route. Like it enters this condition `!$request->ajax()` and breaks this CLI worker.

**AjaxController's constructor**

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    if (!$request->ajax()) 
    {
        abort(403);
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::controller('ajax', 'AjaxController');
```

Any thoughts how could I get route list without removing this condition?

Comment: In which file do you have this code? Try removing the route to this controller, does everything work than?

Comment: just edited, in AjaxController

Comment: when route is removed it works

Comment: Could you post the methods and complete routes from AjaxController?

Comment: Other routes are not important as this is working when this specific route is removed. As for other methods they are all working over AJAX, and they are also not important because I see in error log that `abort(403);` is the line where CLI command breaks

Answer (score 1):

This is normal because your command line call is not an ajax. 
In this case, it enters in the condition and makes the abort(403) that calls the `[Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException]`. 
Maybe if you want the route list without removing this condition you could override the render function in `App\Exceptions\Handler` with something likes this:

```
    public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        if (view()->exists('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode()))
        {
            return response()->view('errors.'.$e->getStatusCode(), [], $e->getStatusCode());
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }
    }
```

See https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-custom-error-pages

Comment: I don't want JSON response in every 403 HTTP exception

Comment: I edited the code. You can create your custom error pages. In this case, you will have to create the view resources/views/errors/403.blade.php.

Comment: This is not solving the initial problem